# Switch case inside of 'value' for CDataColumn

Tags: php, yii

Does anyone know how to display a switch/case value in CGridView column field?

I've got an entry in the DB for types 'Picture', 'Video', 'Audio', 'Drawing', in the CGridView however I would like to display the Text instead of 1, 2, 3, 4.

I've found this online, but this only apply for 2 values, i need 4,

```
array(
  'name'=>'column_name',
  'type'=>'HTML',
  'value'=>'($data->gender=="1")?"Male":"Female"',
),
```

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array(
  'name'=>'column_name',
  'type'=>'HTML',
  'value'=>function($data){
      $result = 'unknown';
      //($data->gender=="1")?"Male":"Female"
      switch($data->gender)
     {
       case 'male':
       $result = 'this was male';
       break;
     }
     return $result;
   },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function to determine the value.

```
'value'=>array($this,'getData')
```

In your controllor, create a function named getData

```
public function getData($data,$row){
 switch($data['gender']){
  <your codes here to return the result>
 }
}
```